# C# / XAML: How to declare a textbox in XAML code that is used in a class

Tags: c#, class, xaml, declare

How do I declare a textbox in the XAML code that is used in a class? I copied all the source code from the MainWindow.xaml.cs to another class because the MainWindow is getting to big.

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

The following causes the error:

```
TextChanged="textBox_1_Kurzbeschreibung_TextChanged"
```

**EDIT:** The following statement solved the problem.

*~closed.*

Comment: If a class is getting "too big", that's a great sign that your class is doing too much and should be refactored into smaller classes.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. I want classes to do the jobs of the MainWindow.xaml.cs - but as you can see, it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple make the class partial, and then use the same name in the two classes.

```
public partial class MyClass
{
     // code....
}
```

The other class need to be equal:

```
public partial class MyClass
{
     // code....
}
```

From MSDN:

"Partial type definitions allow for the definition of a class, struct, or interface to be split into multiple files

See more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbx7zzdd.aspx

Comment: 1. public partial class MainWindow : Window --> 2. public partial class Template --> --> --> I did that but it's still not working. Do you know what I did wrong?

Comment: Yes, the name of both classes must be the same

Comment: Thanks it works BETTER. I can run my application now, but the problem is, that I get an error message when I enter something to the named textbox. The error message says something about "NEW is missing".

Comment: EDIT: Problem fixed - it was just a fallacy. ;) --> ~closed.